# discord.py 2.0 modal slashcommand was not sync at guild

Tags: discord.py

trying to make a text input box a slash command, but the slash command is not sync in the guild.exclude modal function, it is synced.

the command file run on cogs

no error message

and here is my code

if you need main
reply message

> > cog file

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands,ui
from discord.ext import commands
import interactions

class Box(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('input text')
        

        
class SurveyModal(ui.Modal, title='Survey'):
    name= ui.TextInput(label='Name')
    answer = ui.TextInput(label='q1', style= discord.TextStyle.short)
    async def on_submit(self,interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('thanks')
    
    @app_commands.command(name="input", description="test input")
    async def box(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(SurveyModal())

    

        
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Box(bot), guilds=[discord.Object(id='975632483750137878')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a command inside of a modal... Put the command inside of the *cog*, which is what cogs are for. The modal is just for the pop-up in Discord.

Comment: and i found the answer. ``await interaction.response.send_modal(self.SurveyModal())``

Comment: Huh? That doesn't make any sense. The modal class isn't inside of another class, so there shouldn't be a `self` there.

Comment: i fallow your advice and still have a problem so add self. then it was work!  thx you